# Javascript calls WCF Service with error namespace is not defined

Tags: javascript, wcf, service, call, undefined

I'm working on a maintainance phase of a website and I'm getting problems with it.
There's an issue which relates to Javascript trying to call a WCF Service that throw an error on javascript 'Uncaught ReferenceError'

Here is the scope of that script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    Utility.blockUI();
    AwmsUI.Actions.page_id = Utility.UrlParam("pid");
    AwmsUI.Actions.mode = Utility.UrlParam("mode");
    wcf.wmsService.GetAllOnlineComponentType(AwmsUI.Actions.page_id, AwmsUI.Actions.newComponentType);
```

That's just a part of the whole long function. 
The error occurs at the last line where it should call the service 'wmsService' in namespace 'wcf'.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "wcf")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class wmsService
{ blah blah ... }
```

I've checked the wcf service which hosted in my local iis and it seems not found (display blank). 
I've checked the wcf service which hosted in customer's dev env and it displays 'Endpoint not found'. 
The page is running just fine on customer's dev env but it stucks on my site. 
I've did get latest sourcecode and compared with the responsity there to make sure no changes were made.

I think I must have made mistakes somewhere in configuration or something but I have no idea what should I correct.
Could you guys please help me out?

I'm running on IIS 7 using AppPool Classic 2.0

Thanks & Regards
Hoang

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to figure out the issue myself

The solution was:

Run cmd.exec and execute:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\servicemodelreg.exe -i

or on 32 bit:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation>ServiceModelReg.exe -i